# In osx 10.10 running Apache 2.4, in localhost/username some pages are "randomly" forbidden while others are now

Tags: macos, apache

I have set up a webserver for the first time.

When I type http://localhost/yaniv/index.html in the browser, the page loads perfectly. 
When I do the same with register.html also, no problem,
but many other files, like "profile.html" and many other return an error:

Permission denied.

This is my user.conf file

```
<Directory "/Users/yaniv/Sites/">
 Options Indexes MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 # OSX 10.10 / Apache 2.4
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is a permission issue on file system level.

Keep in mind that the http server process is executed under a specific user account. That account requires access to the files, typically read access. It is easy to miss that step when you create files using an ordinary user account.

A typical solution on unixoid systems (so Mac OS too) is to use group permissions. You you assign all the files to the group the http server account belongs to and grant group read access to all files. You can "automate" this by means of the `umask` feature in modern shells. You can read about that in the man pages (if you have them installed).

Comment: Well, as said: you have to check the precise permissions to access those files. Whom do those files belong? What account, what group? What file system permissions do they have? Now compare this to the user account the http server is executed under. Probably there is no access granted for that account.

Comment: btw, I moved all the files to root/library/webserver/documents and still, only some of the files work and some do not. Note, all files are in the same folder.

Comment: That is not of interest. Question is about their permissions. Why don't you check what I mentioned?